# Indent-text in the SelectField in Django

Tags: django, select, space, indentation

I am trying to indent text in a multiple choice field.

```
def __init__(self):
    super(RegisterFull,self).__init__()
    sectorList = Sector.objects.all()    

sArray = []    
for s in sectorList:    
    sArray.append((s.id,"    "+s.__unicode__()))
self.fields["subsector"].choices = sArray
```

I have tried this and

```
sArray.append((s.id,"&nbsp;&nbsp;"+s.__unicode__()))
```

However, I couldn't achieve what I wanted because the "&" character is replaced by & (of course) and empty space is trimmed. Why, when html page is created?

Could you suggest a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using cascading style sheets (CSS) to format the fields as you want.  HTML is supposed to focus mainly on the layout of your document, while CSS can do the fine tuning of formating.  So add a class to the widget of your Form;

e.g.,

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'indented'}))
```

and then have in CSS at the top of the template (or move to an separate style sheet)

```
<style type="text/css">
.indented {
    text-indent: 20px;
}
</style>
```

If you really wanted, you could do something simpler like:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'text-indent: 20px;'})).
```

EDIT: To get your solution to work (with `&nbsp;`)

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def __init__(self):
    super(RegisterFull,self).__init__()
    sectorList = Sector.objects.all()    

    sArray = []    
    for s in sectorList:    
        sArray.append((s.id,mark_safe("&nbsp; &nbsp; "+s.__unicode__())))
        self.fields["subsector"].choices = sArray
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'd like to use multiplechoicefield.There are several items in the list and not all of them are indented. I want to determine the intentede ones at the serverside and render them as html.

Comment: @user763256: I'd still suggest doing a solution in CSS, potentially changing the CSS class to be indented or not, based on your criteria server side.  HTML renders consecutive whitespace as a single whitespace.  You can use non-breaking space `&nbsp;` but it is inelegant and you'll have to deal with properly escaping/unescaping the html, make sure its marked safe, etc.

Comment: @user763256: See the bottom of my answer, where you `mark_safe` the `&nbsp;` to get it to render as unicode in your template.  Be careful with using `mark_safe` to not let yourself be vulnerable to CSRF attacks.  E.g., if users can create choices like specify Foreign key fields that appear in multiple choice text, they could link to javascript code that could do something you don't want to happen.

Comment: I think I misunderstood at first when you suggest "text-indent". I applied "text-indet" style to the options and it works perfect!